# Getting a list of documents with a maximum field value from CouchDB view

Tags: couchdb, mapreduce

Let's say I have blog entries like these in my CouchDB database:

```
{"name":"Mary", "postdate":"20110412", "subject":"this", "message":"blah"}
{"name":"Joe", "postdate":"20110411", "subject":"that", "message":"yadda"}
{"name":"Mary", "postdate":"20110411", "subject":"and this", "message":"blah-blah"}
{"name":"Joe", "postdate":"20110410", "subject":"And other thing", "message":"yada-yada"}
{"name":"Jane", "postdate":"20110409", "subject":"Serious stuff", "message":"Not really"}
```

It's pretty easy to get a list of all posts. But how do I get a list of latest posts from all the users?

Like that:

```
{"name":"Mary", "postdate":"20110412", "subject":"this", "message":"blah"}
{"name":"Joe", "postdate":"20110411", "subject":"that", "message":"yadda"}
{"name":"Jane", "postdate":"20110409", "subject":"Serious stuff", "message":"Not really"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this map function:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.postdate && doc.name) {
    emit([doc.name, doc.postdate], 1);
  }
}
```

and the following reduce function:

```
function(keys, values, rereduce) {
  var max = 0,
      ks = rereduce ? values : keys;

  for (var i = 1, l = ks.length; i < l; ++i) {
    if (ks[max][0][1] < ks[i][0][1]) max = i;
  }
  return ks[max];
}
```

and query it with `group_level=1`. It gives you the `_id` of the posts, then you can retrieve them all with a single query with [the `keys` parameter or using a POST](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options).

I am not sure if this is the best approach, but it seems to work.

**UPDATE:** fixed map to handle rereduce correctly.

Comment: I tried something like that. This is what I get in return when I access the view: "error":"reduce_overflow_error","reason":"Reduce output must shrink more rapidly: Current output:...        Could be because my documents in reality are quite big, about 7-10K.

Comment: I have just tried loading 30000 documents and it works for me. But I have used only four different `doc.name`s. May be you have many users whit few posts per user? Have you tried the updated version?

Comment: Please note I have also updated the map function to `emit([doc.name, doc.postdate], 1)`, not `emit([doc.name, doc.postdate], doc)`.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to emit the postdate as the key because keys are sorted. For example, this is what your map function will look like...

```
function(doc) {
  if(doc.postdate) {
    emit(doc.postdate, doc);
  }
}
```

That will give you all the docs sorted ascending by postdate. If you want descending then query with `?descending=true`

Cheers.

Comment: That would, unfortunately, include all posts from, say, Mary, while I am looking for only the latest one. Is is asking too much from CouchDB?

Comment: You can do that no problem! Just make sure you're descending and call the URL using the limit parameter like this: `?descending=true&limit=1`. Cheers.

Comment: Ah, I see: you want the latest per user, not the latest in general. This is only possible by doing multiple calls and using complex keys. For example, your key structure would be `[doc.name, doc.postdate]` and then you could query `?startkey=["Mary"]&endkey=["Mary",{}]&descending=true&limit=1` to get Mary's latest post.

Comment: Thank you Sam. I think that answers my question. It's unfortunate that I have to use multiple calls. It's not feasible when database has close to a million persons.

Comment: If that's the case, then you could maintain the list yourself in an additional document. Give it an _id of "latestPosts" or something like that. Also take a look at couchdb-lucene for additional, more traditional, querying functionality. Cheers.